# python monitor computer internet traffic

Tags: python, post, get, python-requests, monitor

I need a way of monitoring all the incoming and outgoing data of the computer I'm using. This could be a way of showing all the POST and GET methods used when loading a web page (like when you click inspect element and the network tab). Is there a python library I could use for this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use pyshark!
It's like wireshark but it's made for python!
[Check the github docs](https://github.com/KimiNewt/pyshark/)